# How to correct Syntax error with my elif, if statement. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

```
import sys

import pygame


def check_events(ship):

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # Move the ship to the right.
            ship.moving_right = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = False

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    '''Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen.'''
```

Error:

```
File "/home/mark/python_work/game_functions.py", line 8
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: You can't have an `elif` without an `if`. Change the first one to an `if`.

Answer (score 2):

In your function, your first condition should start with an `if`.

```
def check_events(ship):

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # <--- note the change here
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # Move the ship to the right.
            ship.moving_right = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `elif` without an `if` preceding it. Just change the first `elif` to an `if`.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will try that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use elif before an if statement. Elif cannot be used without an if statement.
This is the right syntax.
import sys

import pygame

def check_events(ship):

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        # Move the ship to the right.
        ship.moving_right = True

elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
```

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    '''Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen.'''

Comment: Thank you. Just when you think it could be a difficult task, its something as simple as that! appreciate it.